# unable to load c dll module in Lua

Tags: c++, dll, lua

I try to test loading a c++ dll module in Lua using "require", below is the c++ module file

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
    #include "lua/lualib.h"
    #include "lua/lauxlib.h"
    #include "lua/lua.h"

    __declspec(dllexport) int luaopen_mylib(lua_State* L);
}

using namespace std;

static int libFunc1(lua_State* L)
{
    int n = lua_gettop(L);
    printf("in myfunc stack, arg number: %d\n", n);
    if (lua_isstring(L, -1))
    {
        std::cout << lua_tostring(L, -1) << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "invalid arg" << std::endl;
    }
    return 1;
}

static const struct luaL_Reg mylib[] = {{"func1", libFunc1}, {NULL, NULL}};

int luaopen_mylib(lua_State* L)
{
    cout << "loading my lib" << endl;
    luaL_newlib(L, mylib);
    return 1;
}
```

I compiled this cpp file into dll using g++ in msys:

```
g++    -c -o mylib.o mylib.cpp
g++ -shared -o mylib.dll mylib.o -Llua -llua5.3.0
```

until now everything work fine, and I got the mylib.dll file too. but when I try to load the module, I got the error msg:

```
> require("mylib")
error loading module 'mylib' from file '.\mylib.dll':
        找不到指定的程序。

stack traceback:
        [C]: in ?
        [C]: in function 'require'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

the Chinese characters above mean:

```
The specified function could not be found.
```

I think the "specified function" mean the "luaopen_mylib", but the cpp file do have the function:luaopen_mylib, WHAT IS GOING WRONG?

Comment: What does the Chinese characters mean?

Comment: sorry for that! the Chinese characters mean:The specified function could not be found.

Answer (score 2):

It might be some name mangling problem. Try:

```
extern "C" 
{
    int luaopen_mylib(lua_State* L)
    {
        cout << "loading my lib" << endl;
        luaL_newlib(L, mylib);
        return 1;
    }
}
```