# Unable to use a C++ module from Lua

Tags: c++, lua

I'm trying to use a function written in C++ from lua. Given below is the cpp file:

```
extern "C"
{
#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include "lualib.h"
}

static int  add_5(lua_State *L)
{
  double d = lua_tonumber(L, 1); /* get argument */
  d=d+5;
  lua_pushnumber(L, d); /* push result */
  return 1; /* number of results */
}

static const struct luaL_Reg mylib [] =
{
  {"add_5", add_5},
  {NULL, NULL} /* sentinel */
};

int luaopen_mylib (lua_State *L)
{
  //luaL_newlib(L, mylib); //This is not working.
  luaL_register(L, NULL, mylib);
  return 1;
}
```

I compiled the above code by g++ using the following command:

```
g++ -shared -o mylib.so test.cpp -fPIC
```

I'm getting the following error on the lua interpreter:

```
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> local temp = require "mylib"
error loading module 'mylib' from file './mylib.so':
        ./mylib.so: undefined symbol: luaopen_mylib
stack traceback:
        [C]: ?
        [C]: in function 'require'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

**Edit 1**: As per the [suggested link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33865875/unable-to-load-c-dll-module-in-lua), I've enclosed luaopen_mylib function inside an extern "C" block. The error which I was getting earlier has been replaced by a new error now. Now I'm getting this:

```
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> local temp = require "mylib"
attempt to index a string value
stack traceback:
        [C]: ?
        [C]: in function 'require'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

**Edit 2**: I've added a new question @ ['Attempt to index a string value' error while loading a c++ module in lua](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57290650/5701173)

Comment: Probably because of name mangling when exporting a function from C++.

Comment: @Sneftel I've added some new observations.

Comment: @VishalSharma It sounds like you have a different question now. You should ask that as a new question, rather than editing this one to change what it's asking about.

Comment: @Sneftel I've changed the question's title now

Comment: @VishalSharma Your edit is clearly asking a completely different question. I suggest opening a new question instead, as I don't see this one getting re-opened.

Comment: I've created a new question @ https://stackoverflow.com/q/57290650/5701173