# 'Attempt to index a string value' error while loading a c++ module in lua

Tags: c++, lua

I'm trying to use a function written in C++ from lua. Given below is the cpp file:

```
extern "C"
{
#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include "lualib.h"
}

static int  add_5(lua_State *L)
{
  double d = lua_tonumber(L, 1); /* get argument */
  d=d+5;
  lua_pushnumber(L, d); /* push result */
  return 1; /* number of results */
}

static const struct luaL_Reg mylib [] =
{
  {"add_5", add_5},
  {NULL, NULL} /* sentinel */
};

extern "C"
{
  int luaopen_mylib (lua_State *L)
  {
    //luaL_newlib(L, mylib);
    luaL_register(L, NULL, mylib);
    return 1;
  }
}
```

I compiled the above code by g++ using the following command:

```
g++ -shared -o mylib.so test.cpp -fPIC
```

I'm getting the following error on the lua interpreter:

```
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> local temp = require "mylib"
attempt to index a string value
stack traceback:
        [C]: ?
        [C]: in function 'require'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

Please note that I can't upgrade the version of Lua due to some reasons.

Comment: If you have a solution, write an answer. Don't put the answer in the question. The question is for... the question. Thanks.

Comment: ok. Will keep that in mind from now on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument to `luaL_register` is the library name. You can leave it as `NULL`, but if you do, `luaL_register` will try to insert the registered functions into the table it expects to find on the top of the stack (and in your code there's no table on top of the stack). For the general case of registering a library, it's easiest to pass your library name as the second parameter.

Note that LHF suggests *not* doing it that way, since it automatically puts the libary's table into the global table, whereas the user of the library might want to have it only as a local variable. The alternative is to create your own table with `lua_newtable` before calling `luaL_register` (with a null name).

Comment: I disagree with the last sentence. The common recommendation is that libraries should not create globals.

Comment: @lhf Well, you'd know. :-) But my impression was that as of 5.1, it was considered reasonable practice to register libraries into the global table, while that was phased out in later versions with luaL_register in favor of luaL_newlib.

Comment: Your impression is correct. But there is no need to keep on doing that today even if you use Lua 5.1. For instance, all of my libraries work for 5.1 but none creates globals.

Comment: As I've been learning the 5.1 API, I've found that one way to pass a null value to the second parameter of register is to create a const of char pointers with no value before hand and pass that. ex: `const char* x;` (I don't know C so sorry if I phrased that wrong technically, explanation might be bad but the code should work). That should be a little easier than creating a new table (I could not figure out how to pass the null newtable to luaL_register). Just leaving this for people learning like me.